# Perl Template-Toolkit doesn't report an error when using a bogus filename

Tags: perl, error-handling, template-toolkit

In Template Toolkit in Perl, I'm getting two errors instead of one.

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&fatal;

print template('home.htssdfgsml');

sub template {
# --------------------------------------------------------------
#
  my ($file, $vars) = @_;
  my ($output, $template);

  my $config = {
      INCLUDE_PATH => $TEMPLATE_PATH
  };
  $template = Template->new($config);
  $template->process($file, $vars, \$output) || die Template->error;

  return $output;
}
sub fatal {
# --------------------------------------------------------------
#
  my $msg   = shift;

  print_header();

  print "<p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>A fatal error has occured:</font></p><blockquote><pre>$msg</pre></blockquote></font></p>\n";
}
```

and I get this output with two errors instead of one:

```
A fatal error has occured:

file error - home.htssssml: not found


A fatal error has occured:

file error - home.htssssml: not found at /var/path/path/file.pm line
29.
```

Any suggestions on how to just print one error?

Comment: Using your sample script and filling some values in, I cannot reproduce the problem. The script dies with an error: `file error - abcdef.html: not found`. (This is Template-Toolkit 2.24)

Comment: I edited the post to give more information.  Any suggestions on why I'm getting two errors?

Answer (score 1):

Okay this **return if $^S** apparently fixes it so that it only gives one error (including the line number)

```
sub fatal {
# --------------------------------------------------------------
#
  return if $^S;
  my $msg   = shift;

  print_header();

  print "<p><font face='Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica' size=2>A fatal error has occured:</font></p><blockquote><pre>$msg</pre></blockquote></font></p>\n";
}
```

This seems like bad code since it checks for a die in an eval.  Does this seem adequate?

Comment: Checking the value of `$^S` is indeed the fix here. Generally, setting `$SIG{__DIE__}` may be dangerous. See also `perldoc perlvar`, especially the paragraph beginning with "Due to an implementation glitch..."